# Why am I not getting a railroad production bonus?

Tags: civilization-5

I connected all my cities, including the one in the screenshot, to my capital city (lower left in the screenshot).

Shouldn't I be getting a railroad production bonus of 25%? I remember that I used to get such a bonus.

[image: Civ 5 showing a city connected to capital via railroad without getting railroad bonus]

Comment: Are you using any mods?

Comment: None. However, a few turns later I suddenly head the bonus. Does it take three or four turns for them to start appearing?

Comment: that's weird...

Comment: Were there any enemy units breaking your trade route?

Comment: You can see my trade route. There are no enemies on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem went away on its own a few turns later.